# What are physical scenarious which can be modeled as multiplicative noise?

Tags: noise

Consider $s(t)$ as the signal, $w(t)$ as the noise, and $y(t)$ as the captured signal. Usage of additive noise model, that is $y(t)=s(t)+w(t)$, is quite wide spread, example in speech and audio signal enhancement, and is also physically convincing to hypothesize. The convolutive noise model,that is $y(t)=s(t)\star w(t)$, where, delayed copies of the signal overlap together is another widespread model. A physically relevant scenario for this is reverberation modelling.

My question is - Is there a physical motivation to model noisy signal using multiplicative noise model, that is $y(t)=s(t)w(t)$? I am unable to think about any convincing physical domain examples where this happens in reality.

Comment: Useful [link 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_noise), useful [link 2](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/13895/which-domain-used-for-denoising-additive-and-multiplicative-noises)

Comment: well, remember what a frequency mixer is: a mutliplicator. Now, what happens when you feed in additive-noisy signals to that?

Comment: Thank you @MarcusMüller Yes, frequency mixer can be interpreted as a modulation - shifting the baseband frequency content. My question is where do we encounter such modulation (or frequency mixing) happening directly in the signal model before the signal is acquired.

Comment: @Gilles Thank you for the link. However, enough physical domain examples are not available there. I see that, channel delay in analog demodulation can result in a multiplicative noise (a constant factor), and this may also be time-varying. Are there any more examples for 1-D signals (not images)?

Comment: @Neeks , you're welcome. Here is [another useful link](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/26630/when-modelling-noise-how-do-they-decide-whether-additive-or-multiplicative?rq=1).

Comment: @Gilles Thank you again. But not of much help. In fact, I am wondering why is reverberation considered as multiplicative noise there?

Answer (score 3):

In communications, a very important multiplicative model is a flat fading channel where the received signal can be modeled as

$$y(t)=h(t)\cdot s(t)+n(t)\tag{1}$$

where $h(t)$ is the time-varying attenuation caused by the channel, and $n(t)$ is additive noise.